# how to make a stream of Map[String, Any] using flink

Tags: json, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

let's assume that we have this json

```
{
  "Account Informations": {
    "User Info": {
      "User Name": "Albert Goldstein",
      "Date": "03/27/2015 08:35:11",
      "Location": "New York, USA"
    },
    "User": {
      "Email": "FlinkIsDifficult@gmail.com",
      "Password": "*******"
    }
  }
}
```

as a DataStream i want to get another JSON which contains

```
{
        "User": {
          "Email": "FlinkIsDifficult@gmail.com",
          "Password": "*******"
        }
}
```

also is there any way to parse the document by field ? like get("Email") and it returns "FlinkIsDifficult@gmail.com" ??

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the JSON like you would in any other Java or Scala program. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) for help with doing this in Java. You can then apply whatever approach you choose inside of a Flink map() or flatmap() function to do the transformation.

If your JSON is coming from Kafka, you might rather use a [KafkaJsonTableSource](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/sourceSinks.html#kafkajsontablesource).